# Javascript adding numbers as strings

Tags: javascript, variables, math, addition

I have the following code which interprets the numbers as strings and adds them like 100300 instead of 400:

```
var rate = document.getElementById('pur_price').value;
var pprice = document.getElementById('pur_price').value;
var rate1 = document.getElementById('select2').value;
var refurb = 300;
document.getElementById('avg_claim_rate').value=id;
document.getElementById('amount_claim').value=pprice+refurb;
```

it's the pprice and refurb field, so if pprice=100 and refurb=300, I expect it to show 400, where as at the moment it shows 100300

Comment: Do you know the difference between PHP and JavaScript?

Comment: U need to parse the input values with `parseFloat` before doing calculations with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = +pprice + + refurb;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `parseInt` function:

```
var pprice = parseInt(document.getElementById('pur_price').value, , 10);
var rate1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('select2').value, , 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function  parseInt() it can be:

```
document.getElementById('avg_claim_rate').value=id;
document.getElementById('amount_claim').value=parseInt(pprice)+refurb;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @sergio said, you can use JavaScript's built in parseInt function.  Just for reference, you can multiply it by one.  JavaScript always converts a string to a number if you multiply it.  So you could do something like this:

```js
var num1 = "300";
var num2 = "100";

var num1 = num1 * 1; // Converts string to the number 300
var num2 = num2 * 1;

document.getElementById('number').value = num1+num2;
```

```html
<input id="number"/>
```

This is just an alternate way to do the same thing.  Use whatever is easiest for you.  Hope that helps!