# Addition using Variations

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to do some addition whilst using Variations as my `numbers` 
(E.g.: `var Total = Purchaseprice + SalesTax` [Keep in mind `Purchaseprice = 10` and `SalesTax = 1.5`]) I always end up with `101.5` instead of `11.5`. I know I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm not so sure how to make it say what I want..

Comment: No doubt adding them together as strings rather than integers....

Comment: Show us your *actual* code, don't describe your code to us.

Comment: You are adding strings. Try prefixing your values with a `+`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript adding numbers as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866468/javascript-adding-numbers-as-strings)

Comment: @Amy He is showing us his code but unfortunately unformatted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your code to see how you're turning your numbers into strings. Chances are you are getting your values from an input field so I'm going to guess you're doing something like this:

```
var firstValue = document.getElementById('firstValueInput').value;
var secondValue = document.getElementById('secondValueInput').value;
var total = firstValue + secondValue;
```

If you are doing something like that then you're not accounting for the fact that the `value` property is always a string. The users might be typing numbers but they can also type letters so the variable is a string that can contain all sorts of characters.

What you need to do is validate the user input to ensure they can only enter numbers, and then you need to convert the string to a number once you know the string only contains numbers. Here's how you can use the global `parseInt` function to convert the user's input to a number type:

```
var firstValue = document.getElementById('firstValueInput').value;
var secondValue = document.getElementById('secondValueInput').value;
var total = parseInt(firstValue) + parseInt(secondValue);
```

[Here's a demo.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwKWZG)